# My JavaScript If block compares the condition with the old values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 separate AJAX requests in my functions which get fired based upon the value in radio button but on every **SECOND** request, javascript retains the old value for **radio** and it compares it with the old value.

```
    $('.send-quote').click(function (e) {
 var formData = $('#manualBooking').serializeArray();
//this is the value for If check
 var radio = formData[13].value;

 if (radio === "yes") {
        debugger;

        $form.validate({
            errorClass: 'customErrorClass',
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                depdate: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtAddresspickupFromAirport: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtAddressdropOffFromAirport: {
                    required: true
                },
                flight: {
                    required: true
                },
                passenger: {
                    required: true
                },
                luggage: {
                    required: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true
                },
                lang: {
                    required: true
                },
                hours: {
                    required: true
                },
                days: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: "*Please specify a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {

//this function gets hit if the value for radio was 'yes' the first time

                var formDatas = $('#manualBooking').serializeArray();

                var name = formDatas[0].value;
                var contact = formDatas[1].value;
                var email = formDatas[2].value;
                var bookingDate = formDatas[3].value;
                var pickupLocation = formDatas[4].value;
                var dropOffLocation = formDatas[5].value;
                var flight = formDatas[6].value;
                var passenger = formDatas[7].value;
                var luggage = formDatas[8].value;
                var message = formDatas[9].value;
                var language = formDatas[10].value;
                var hours = formDatas[11].value;
                var days = formDatas[12].value;



                //inside yes
                debugger;

                var dataObj =
                    {
                        Name: name,
                        ContactNo: contact,
                        Email: email,
                        BookingDateTime: bookingDate,
                        PickUpLocation: pickupLocation,
                        DropOffLocation: dropOffLocation,
                        FlightNumber: flight,
                        Passenger: passenger,
                        Luggage: luggage,
                        Message: message,
                        Language: language,
                        HoursNeeded: hours,
                        DaysNeeded: days
                    };
                debugger;
                alert('inside YES');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/InsertManualBookingForm',
                    cache: false,
                    data: dataObj,
                    success: function (data) {
                        swal("an email will be sent to you shortly", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });

                        //   document.getElementById("manualBooking").reset();

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
  if (radio === "no") {

        $form.validate({
            errorClass: 'customErrorClass',
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                depdate: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtAddresspickupFromAirport: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtAddressdropOffFromAirport: {
                    required: true
                },
                flight: {
                    required: true
                },
                passenger: {
                    required: true
                },
                luggage: {
                    required: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: "*Please specify a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
//this gets hit if the value for **radio** was 'no' the first time

                var formDatas = $('#manualBooking').serializeArray();

                var name = formDatas[0].value;
                var contact = formDatas[1].value;
                var email = formDatas[2].value;
                var bookingDate = formDatas[3].value;
                var pickupLocation = formDatas[4].value;
                var dropOffLocation = formDatas[5].value;
                var flight = formDatas[6].value;
                var passenger = formDatas[7].value;
                var luggage = formDatas[8].value;
                var message = formDatas[9].value;
                var language = formDatas[10].value;
                var hours = formDatas[11].value;
                var days = formDatas[12].value;


                alert('inside noo');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/InsertManualBookingForm',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        Name: name,
                        ContactNo: contact,
                        Email: email,
                        BookingDateTime: bookingDate,
                        PickUpLocation: pickupLocation,
                        DropOffLocation: dropOffLocation,
                        FlightNumber: flight,
                        Passenger: passenger,
                        Luggage: luggage,
                        Message: message,
                        Language: '',
                        HoursNeeded: '',
                        DaysNeeded: ''
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        swal("an email will be sent to you shortly", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });

                        //   document.getElementById("manualBooking").reset();

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
});
```

so every time I change the radio button value AJAX request for the first value of radio button is made. I believe it is because of something related to closure or hoisting but I'm not really sure and don't know how to make it work. any help will be appreciated

Comment: We need to see more of your code to help you. Specifically where and how you update the inputs and the event handler this code runs under

Comment: Sure, Let me update my answer

Comment: You need to update the `radio` value `onchange`

Comment: just to further explain @Adelin comment - you take the value before anything is even set (or perhaps it is set, but at the time of button submit). You need to add the change eventHandler to pick up the value each time

Comment: when I tried to debug the code, on 4th line it shows the new value [e.g radio==="no" ]for radio button but still, it hits inside the code with a condition radio==="yes".

Comment: Is this `.send-quote` your radiobutton? Then, yes, you should change the event handler like other people say

Comment: nope, .send-quote is a submit button